# Transit Visa at London Heathrow

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, lhr, belgium

I am traveling to India(New Delhi) On 29th December 2020. And I have Belgian -PR Card Holder with electronic Chip, but I have an Indian Passport. My Flight is from Brussels to London Heathrow Via British Airways with 6 Hours Layover and then connecting flight via Air India to Delhi. Do I need a Transit Visa for changing my Flight at London Heathrow airport or Not ? also I have to change terminal T5 to Terminal T2 for connecting flight. please advice!

Comment: Information about moving between terminals is available here https://www.heathrow.com/at-the-airport/airport-maps/travel-between-terminals

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa